# Need to filter table before using form to update. MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I have a form that I would like to use to update a table.

There are 600 lines in this table.

I have a couple of query that will return which lines i need to update. And I only want to show these lines in the update form.

I tried doing a left join make table. Then opening that table with the form. But error I'm getting is that the table is locked. It will run fine when the form is closed.

I wrote the macro to close the form then run the left join make table. Then open the form.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to filters the table without doing the left join?

Comment: Why do you tag ms-access 2007, 2010, 2013? If that's for getting more attention this is not a good idea. Then show what you have tried. VBA code and SQL, add details. Your question is not answerable in that shape and will probably be vote-closed

Comment: I type this out on my phone. So I didn't post any of my examples. I will as soon as I get back to my desk. Sorry about multiple tags. I'm working on access 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your form and set the forms recordsource to the table directly.

Click on the ... next to the record source and say yes when it asks if you want to build a query based on the table.

Build your query to filter to the records and fields your want then close the query and save. This should give you a form with only the records you want to edit.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you minty. Another thing that worked for me was a select query. With an in(select.field from table) in the criteria.

Comment: I always think it is safer to have the forms specific query saved within the form rather than as a saved query. 

Later on, If you ever forget the saved query is used for that form and changed it you could "break" the way the form works.